# Azure functions and Azure KeyVault communicating through service endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault, azure-virtual-network

I have setup and Azure KeyVault with vNET firewalls activated. I also setup an Azure Functions App (Premium, Linux, Python) with vNET integration. I've added the function app's subnet also as service endpoint on key vault. However I am still not able to access the key vault from the azure function.

I get an error message saying that the Azure Functions IP (public IP) cannot access the Key Vault.

Am I missing something? Or is it something that just doesn't work at the moment?

Whitelisting the azure functions IP within Keyvault isn't what I am looking for, since the communication would still go through public endpoint.

Thanks!

Comment: What error are you seeing?  Have you added an access policy to the keyvault for the Function App?

Comment: @DreadedFrost Yes I did add the key vault access policy. It is more of a networking problem. I get an error message saying that the Functions IP (public IP) cannot access the Key Vault. Key Vault is accessed via Python SDK using its DNS name

Answer (score 0):

You could check the followings:

- Use the [new vNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#regional-vnet-integration). You should meet all the limitations for the regional vNet Integration. This feature requires that the app and the VNet must be in the same region. It also requires an unused subnet for VNet integration.
- Enable the service endpoint `Microsoft.KeyVault` for your function subnet.
- Make sure you have added the correct function subnet in the firewall of Key Vault.

Sometimes, the deployment order or a long time for vNet configuration is important, you could refer to this [working template](https://github.com/ScottHolden/ARMExamples/blob/master/AppService-VnetNew-Storage/deploy.json) to complete deployment.

Comment: Yes I did all that. Have you ever got it working on your end? Im not sure what else I am missing

Comment: Usually, people could work it with that template. I also validate [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-vnet). Is there any error message on your side? Do you narrow down it's a network issue?

Comment: Yes I am definitely sure it is a network issue. I get an error message saying that the Azure Functions IP (public IP) cannot access the Key Vault. Key Vault is accessed via Python SDK using its DNS name.

Comment: The template provided looks like it's for setting up an app service to talk to a storage account in the same subnet.....not anything to do with Key Vault.

Comment: Yes, I mean you can replace the storage account resource with a key vault in your template, just refer to that template to complete your template.

Comment: Any process? if you whitelist [possibleOutboundIpAddresses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses#find-outbound-ip-addresses) to the key vault, Is it working?

Answer (score 0):

So VNet Integration with App Service (Function App) only supports

> Deploy Azure Web App Certificate through Key Vault.

Here is the documentation that lists all ["Trusted Services" Key Vaults supports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/key-vault-overview-vnet-service-endpoints)

Here is another [blog that illustrates the same issue you are facing](https://azidentity.azurewebsites.net/post/2019/01/03/key-vault-firewall-access-by-azure-app-services)

The question does not want to whitelist IPs to the Key Vault but to confirm that the support is the issue recommendation is to white list and see if it works.  If it does that confirms the issue is retrieving secrets by an App Service is not a "Trusted Services" for Key Vault