# How to access Azure Keyvault via private endpoint in Python?

Tags: python, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-identity

For security purpose, I have disabled public access under Networking Tab in Keyvault and have a private endpoint in place. Both keyvault and private endpoint reside in same resource group. I have an app registration for my application for which I have granted access under Access policies in Keyvault.

Using Python SDK,

```
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.identity import ClientSecretCredential as cs


keyVaultName = "<NAME>"
kvURI = "https://<NAME>.vault.azure.net"
AZ_TENANT_ID = '<AZ_TENANT_ID>'
AZ_CLIENT_ID = '<AZ_CLIENT_ID>'
AZ_CLIENT_SECRET = '<AZ_CLIENT_SECRET>'
credential = cs(
            tenant_id=AZ_TENANT_ID,
            client_id=AZ_CLIENT_ID,
            client_secret=AZ_CLIENT_SECRET)

def set_secret(secretname,secretvalue):
        print(credential)
        secret_client = SecretClient(vault_url=kvURI, credential=credential)
        secret = secret_client.set_secret(secretname,secretvalue,enabled=True)
        sec_dic={}
        sec_dic['name']=secret.name
        sec_dic['value']=secret.value
        sec_dic['properties']=secret.properties.version
        return sec_dic
    
xx=set_secret('g','ff')
print(xx)
```

When running this code, I get the follwing error,

```
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (Forbidden) Public network access is disabled and request is not from a trusted service nor via an approved private link.
Code: Forbidden
Message: Public network access is disabled and request is not from a trusted service nor via an approved private link.
Inner error: {
    "code": "ForbiddenByConnection"
}
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I connect to keyvault that has no public access only via private endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment, and got expected results as below:

Firstly, I have done the same process you have explained, and I got same error as you have got:

[image]

So, this error comes when you create a private endpoint.

When you create a private endpoint with a particular Virtual Network-Subnet, you need to create a Virtual Machine where Virtual Network is integrated.

[image]

Then we need to open the Vm created integrated with the above Virtual Network-Subnet, and now when I try to access the key Vault, I got required result as below:

[image]

**References:**

- [azure - Unable to get storage account container details - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75064963/unable-to-get-storage-account-container-details)
- [Azure Key Vault not allow access via private endpoint connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67589490/azure-key-vault-not-allow-access-via-private-endpoint-connection)
- [Azure functions and Azure KeyVault communicating through service endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59570726/azure-functions-and-azure-keyvault-communicating-through-service-endpoint)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was able to find out that this happens only in my localhost and not when it is deployed

Comment: I am glad you find out the answer.